# Get age from the birthday field with type date using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I have a table in a MySQL database with a field of the type `date`. Herein the birthday of a user is stored. Is there a pure SQL way to select the age in years from the field?

Comment: Define PURE SQL way? -- an MySQL specific way? or one that conforms to complete ANSI standards?

Comment: @TransactCharlie it has to work on MySQL, but doesn't have to be MySQL specific. I just meant I don't want to parse the results with PHP or so.

Comment: You can use Stored procedure fo rthis. It has many functions to calculate your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this...

```
SELECT
    id,
    Name,
    DateofBirth,
    ((DATEDIFF(Cast((Select Now()) as Date),
    Cast(DateofBirth as Date)))/365) AS DiffDate
from TABEL1
```

**Edit** Considereing Fact from Transact Charlie....

```
 SELECT
        id,
        Name,
        DateofBirth,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, Cast(DateofBirth as Date),
        Cast((Select Now()) as Date)) AS DiffDate
    from TABEL1
```

Comment: Thanks, but... PhpMyAdmin: 'FUNCTION database.`GetDate()` does not exist'

Comment: That gives me ages like 10,000, 20,000

Comment: try now it returning number of days difference...so divide it by 365 to get in year

Comment: Ah, of course, should've thought of that myself! Great, thanks :)

Comment: @CamilStaps welcome always dont forget to accept it as answer unless you find better answer...

Comment: calculating the number of days and dividing by 365 will break when considering leap years.

Answer (score 2):

Stored Proc example:

```
DATEDIFF(datepart, startdate, enddate)
```

Easier:

```
-- Declare Two DateTime Variable
Declare @Date1 datetime 
Declare @Date2 datetime 
-- Set @Date1 with Current Date
set @Date1 = (SELECT GETDATE());
-- Set @Date2 with 5 days more than @Date1
set @Date2 = (SELECT DATEADD(day, 5,@Date1 ))
-- Get The Date Difference
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @Date1, @Date2) AS DifferenceOfDay
```