# Selecting age groups using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is a follow-up question on [Get age from the birthday field with type date using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17146119/1544337). I have a `date` field in a MySQL database for the birthday of a user and get the age using this query:

```sql
SELECT 
    ROUND(DATEDIFF(
        Cast((SELECT NOW()) as Date),
        Cast(birthday as Date)
    ) / 365, 0) as age
FROM member
```

Now, I need to select the number of people in different age groups. For example, I need to know how many people are in the age group 13-17, 18-21, 22-25, 26-35, 36-50, 51-MAX.

Is that possible using MySQL?

I have thought of `UNION`s, like this:

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(DATEDIFF(
        Cast((SELECT NOW()) as Date),
        Cast(birthday as Date)
    ) / 365, 0) as age,
    1 as agegroup
FROM member WHERE age >=13 AND age <=17

UNION

SELECT 
    ROUND(DATEDIFF(
        Cast((SELECT NOW()) as Date),
        Cast(birthday as Date)
    ) / 365, 0) as age
    2 as agegroup
FROM member WHERE age >=18 AND age <=21
```

But that would be long and ugly. There must be a better way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  AgeGroup
,       count(*)
from    (
        select  case
                when  age between 13 and 17 then 1
                when  age between 18 and 21 then 2
                ...
                end as AgeGroup
        from    (
                SELECT  ROUND(DATEDIFF(Cast(NOW() as Date),
                            Cast(birthday as Date)) / 365, 0) as age
                FROM    YourTable
                ) as SubQueryAlias
        ) as SubQueryAlias2
group by
        AgeGroup
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:-

```
SELECT  AgeRange.MinAge, AgeRange.MaxAge, COUNT(*)
FROM    
(
    SELECT 13 AS MinAge, 17 AS MaxAge
    UNION SELECT 18, 21
    UNION SELECT 22, 25
    UNION SELECT 26, 35
    UNION SELECT 36, 50
    UNION SELECT 51, 9999
) AgeRange
INNER JOIN YourTable
ON ROUND(DATEDIFF(CAST(NOW() as DATE), CAST(birthday as DATE)) / 365, 0) BETWEEN AgeRange.MinAge AND AgeRange.MaxAge 
GROUP BY AgeRange.MinAge, AgeRange.MaxAge
```

Possibly easier to expand if needs be, or to move to using date ranges from a table (so the resulting report could be updated by users easily if required).

Answer (score 0):

If you had the age as a column in a table you would do it like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN age < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS under10,
    SUM(CASE WHEN 10<age AND age <19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS age10to19,
    .
    .
    .
FROM table
```

There are likely to be minor changes because age isn't in its own column or if you want extra or different ranges. I'm sure you can work them out yourself!

Comment: the table is the subselect the OP shows in the question (also you have a typo: ELSE 9 should be ELSE 0)